# how to get gradient of abline in R

Tags: r, plot, line, gradient

I want to get the value of the gradient/slope for a linear model on a scatter plot in R

If for example I have a plot:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
plot(x, y)
abline(lm(y ~ x))
```

The scatter plot now has a line, for which I need to know the gradient. Ideally what I want is a function that can work out the gradients for various x/y combinations, without plotting the graph each time. I can create the function myself, but I am stuck on how to get the gradient.

Comment: `lm(y ~ x)$coefficients[2]` gives the slope of the line in this example. Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: @JakeBurkhead Minor nitpick: generally `coef(lm(y~x))[2]` is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your data and example

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
plot(x, y)
```

Save the linear model you passed to abline, which can be done in-line

```
abline(mod <- lm(y ~ x))
```

Then examine the coefficients of the model `mod` using the `coef()` function

```
coef(mod)

R> coef(mod)
(Intercept)           x 
    0.06667     0.09697
```

The "slope" is the second coefficient. If you want to extract just that one, subset the vector returned by `coef()`, as in

```
coef(mod)[2]

R> coef(mod)[2]
      x 
0.09697
```

Note that I don't recommend assigning to objects as part of an argument to another function like I did above. If your code or scripts gets large then these things can be more difficult to track down or spot by eye. I generally prefer to create objects on their own line. For the above example, that'd mean doing

```
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
abline(mod)
```

which isn't a major difference, but it is easier to spot where `mod` is created and how.

Answer (score 3):

A simple linear regression model has two coefficients which you can extract with the coef function. The slope is the second coefficient.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
fit.lm <-lm(y ~ x)
slope <- coef(fit.lm)[2]
```